# How to Share a Single Page NEXT.js Application as a Standalone HTML File

Tags: html, reactjs, next.js, frontend

I'm facing a challenge with sharing a single-page application built with NEXT.js. My objective is to create a standalone, browser-usable HTML file, similar to how one might share an Excel sheet file. I attempted to use the NEXT.js package tool to generate this file, but it resulted in a folder containing an index.html file that does not function properly when opened in a browser.

Is there a way to export a NEXT.js application into a single, self-contained HTML file that retains full functionality? Any suggestions or alternative approaches to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can't make it a single HTML file and maintain full functionality. It's better to use Next.js as is and host it on Vercel's free tier. Share the code repo for code access and hosted Vercel URL for site access.